# How to add a number to a cell, adding it in a different cell and then clearing

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Let's say I have a number in the cell A1. I want to make so that, if I write a number in the cell A2, it is added in A1 and then cleared in A2. How  do I do that?

Comment: You will need to add some code in VBA.

Comment: I got to that part. I want to know what to write, because the documentation of .gs is kinda vague, and I don't know how to do simple things like selecting cell values, storing in a temporary variable and writing in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this VBA code,

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Address = "$A$2" And IsNumeric(Cells(1, 1)) And IsNumeric(Cells(2, 1)) Then
    Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, 1) + Cells(2, 1)
    Cells(2, 1).ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

This code adds the value in `A1` to `A2`, stores the new value in `A1` and clears the data in cell `A2` whenever a new value is entered in the cell.